# Admin controller throws 404 page not found for my custom extension

Tags: magento-1.9, module, admin-controller

I am creating a **custom extension** with **Magento 1.9.0.1** but got stuck in admin controller as my admin controller throws 404 page not found error. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code 
:
**config.xml**

> app/code/local/Codifiedweb/SurveySource/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Codifiedweb_SurveySource>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Codifiedweb_SurveySource>
    </modules>
    <admin>
    <routers>
      <surveysource>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <modules>
              <codifiedweb_surveysource before="Mage_Adminhtml">Codifiedweb_SurveySource_Adminhtml</codifiedweb_surveysource>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </surveysource>
    </routers>
  </admin>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <surveysource>
                <class>Codifiedweb_SurveySource_Block</class>
            </surveysource>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>   <sales_order_grid>Codifiedweb_SurveySource_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite> 
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
         <helpers>
      <surveysource>
        <class>Codifiedweb_SurveySource_Helper</class>
      </surveysource>
    </helpers>
        <models>
            <surveysource>
                <class>Codifiedweb_SurveySource_Model</class>
            </surveysource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**adminhtml.xml**

> app/code/local/Codifiedweb/SurveySource/etc/adminhtml.xml

I am creating submenu under CMS

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <menu>
            <cms>
                <children>
                    <surveysourcebackend module="surveysource">
                            <title>Survey Statics</title>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            <action>adminhtml/surveysource</action>
                     </surveysourcebackend>
                </children>
            </cms>
        </menu>
    </config>
```

**Controller**

**SurveySourceController.php**

> app/code/local/Codifiedweb/SurveySource/controllers/Adminhtml

```
<?php
class CodifiedWeb_SurveySource_Adminhtml_SurveySourceController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
  public function indexAction()
  {

    // $this->loadLayout();
     //$this->_title($this->__("Survey Statics"));
     //$this->renderLayout();
     echo "Iam  in admin controller";
     exit;
  }
}
```

Where I am doing mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Change **SurveySource** to **Surveysource** module name, controller name .. and update it everywhere

2) The class of your controller, you put **CodifiedWeb** instead of **Codifiedweb**

```
<?php
    class Codifiedweb_Surveysource_Adminhtml_SurveysourceController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
    {
      public function indexAction()
      {

        // $this->loadLayout();
         //$this->_title($this->__("Survey Statics"));
         //$this->renderLayout();
         echo "Iam  in admin controller";
         exit;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I tried as you said but still getting the same 404 error

Comment: I have a quick look to your code you miss other things too, try to clean a cache then logout and login.

Comment: Yes I cleaned the cache and logout and login too.. Would you mind telling me what other things i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need add **acl** in file adminhtml.xml after `</config>`

```
 <acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
               <cms>
                   <children>                
                       <surveysourcebackend translate="title" module="codifiedweb_surveysource">
                    <title>Survey Statics</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                       </surveysourcebackend>
                   </children>
                </cms>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Please see example http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/02/08/magento-create-your-own-admin-controller-in-a-new-tab/

http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited/

Comment: I guess you mean to say before</config> because when i try to add that after </config> my menu disappears. But still showing 404 error